# DbUpdateException while saving entities , one to many relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

have an entity model with `Depot` and `Rayon` entities, such that each `Rayon` must be associated with exactly one `Depot`, and each `Depot` can be associated zero or more `Rayon`.

> Rayon(0..*) <-------> (1) Depot

Here is my code:

```
public void Update(Depot obj)
{
  var testDepot = DepotContainer.DepotSet.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == obj.Id);
  testDepot.Nom = obj.Nom;
  testDepot.Zone = obj.Zone;
  testDepot.Rayons = obj.Rayons;
  DepotContainer.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Depot

```
public partial class Depot
{
 public Depot() { this.Rayons = new HashSet<Rayon>(); }

 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Nom { get; set; }
 public string Zone { get; set; }

 public virtual ICollection<Rayon> Rayons { get; set; }
}
```

### Rayon

```
public partial class Rayon
{
 public Rayon() { this.Article = new HashSet<Article>(); }

 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Code { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }

 public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Article> Article { get; set; }
}
```

While saving changes I  got these error :

> Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Inner Execption

> A relationship from the 'DepotRayon' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Rayon' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

Comment: please post InnerException

Comment: Are you setting the Depot property on Rayon objects? Are you creating new Rayon objects or just relating them to a Depot? if you are not trying to create them, are they attached to the context?

Comment: sorry for the delay abhinav sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the depot's multiplicity must be (0.. 1) because when I remove a Rayon from a Depot the foreign key in the rayon entities become null what make the exception